# Calculate the limit of a real sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I need to show that the following real sequence is convergent. Let $r,l>0$  be constant then the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is defined by
$$ a_n=sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{2n}\right)\sqrt{1+n^2l^2}.$$

Furthermore, I also need to determine the limit (which is $\frac{r}{2}l$).

Thank you in advance for your answers and ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\lim _{ n\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \arcsin { n }  }{ n }  } =1,\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \arcsin { \left( \frac { r }{ 2n }  \right)  }  }{ \left( \frac { r }{ 2n }  \right)  }  } =1$ so

> $$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \arcsin { \left( \frac { r }{ 2n }  \right)  } \sqrt { 1+n^{ 2 }l^{ 2 } }  } =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { \arcsin { \left( \frac { r }{ 2n }  \right)  }  }{ \frac { r }{ 2n }  } \cdot \frac { r }{ 2n } \cdot \sqrt { 1+n^{ 2 }l^{ 2 } }  } =\\ =\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { r }{ 2n } \cdot n\cdot \sqrt { \frac { 1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } } +l^{ 2 } }  } =\color{red}{\frac { lr }{ 2 }} $$

Comment: thank you very much! that was quick! and the first property follows with l'hôpital, am I right?

Comment: you are welcome, I didn't use here L'Hospital's rule, just multiplied and divided  both sides to $\frac { r }{ 2n } $ then, used well-known limit that mentioned above

Comment: I ment the limit $\lim_{n\to 0} \frac{\mathrm{arcsin}\ n }{n}=1$, sorry for the missunderstanding.

Comment: But it's alright. Thanks!